# Puppeteer Web Scraping - Scrape a product with multiple images

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I am trying to build a portfolio with various small projects - currently im working on web scraping.

I am using Puppeteer and am able to scrape basic test websites. However, my questions ends to more advanced uses such as the ability to scrape a product which has multiple images, a typical use case of today.

At the moment i am able to retrieve the 1 single image which is loaded on the page using the correct selector. However, if the product has for example 5 images, i would like to retrieve all 5 images but at the highest resolution and not as the thumbnails which are usually shown as a preview

All help is appreciated

Comment: Please share your site and code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A high-res image will be available on the product's description page. You might need to go to that page to retrieve the URL of the high-resolution image, depending on how the website/platform you are scraping is structured.

Comment: In some cases for example Amazon - they do not have the product images anywhere else on the description page except where the product image usually sits allowing the user to hover, enlarge on click etc. How would this be achieved?

Comment: You can hover with puppeteer. You first need to hover the images manually and inspect the HTML to see how Amazon handles the high-res images on the front-end. When you have that worked out, you easily replicate that in your code. You first need to work it out manually before you can translate the manual work into coding. Let me know if this helps or if you need more clarification.

Comment: Sorry - i am new to Puppeteer, im not sure how the hover etc would work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. This (https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.hover) might help with the hovering. If you feel safe sharing your code, I can take some time off my work to help you finish some things and explain them in the code.